# Bootstrap Dropdown not toggling, just "show" works

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am using the bootstrap drop down for a div that contains buttons. The div appears and all, and I see in the dropdown class that a class of "open" is added and the drop down menu has an attribute of "aria-expanded" set to "true". I am pretty sure the bootstrap is working, but I am missing something. 
Here is my cshtml template:

```
@using entryIconContent = Lifegunk.Engine.Resources.Components.EntryIcon
<div class="entry-icon-wrapper">
    <div class="entry-type"></div>
    <div class="dropdown actions-dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-menu entry-icon-actions">
            <button class='change-btn btn btn-default'>
                <div class="entry-type"></div>
                <span>@entryIconContent.ChangeText</span>
            </button>
            <button class="move-btn btn btn-default">
                <div class="icon-move"></div>
                <span>@entryIconContent.MoveText</span>
            </button>
            <button class='go-btn btn btn-default'>
                <div class="icon-arrow-right"></div>
                <span>@entryIconContent.GoText</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown entry-types-dropdown">
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my snippet of javascript code where I call the .dropdown() func:

```
$entryTypeIcon.click(function () {
            if (isEditMode) {
                $entryTypesDropMenu.dropdown("toggle");
                renderEntryTypes();
            } else {
                $entryActionsDropdown.dropdown("toggle");
            }
            if ($entryTypesDropMenu.is(":visible")) {
                $entryTypesDropMenu.hide();
                $entryActionsDropdown.hide();
            }
        });//end $entryTypeIcon click handler
```

Comment: Are you loading the bootstrap js? It's required for dropdowns.

Comment: Yes, bootstrap is already loaded throughout this entire project

Comment: I have also used "data-toggle=dropdown" in the cshtml to no avail